# Error! The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'

Tags: c#, sql-server, join, entity-framework-core

Hello can someone help me, it said error, I cannot join. Thank you. Error! The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.

```cs
try
{
    var empList = 
        from a in _Db.table_Employee
        join b in _Db.table_Item
            on a.EmpItemId equals b.EmpId into itm
        from b in itm.DefaultIfEmpty()

        select new Employee
        {
            EmpId = a.EmpId,
            EmpName = a.EmpName,
            EmpPosition = a.EmpPosition,
            EmpCompany = a.EmpCompany,
            EmpEmail = a.EmpEmail,
            EmpItemId = a.EmpItemId,
            Item = b == null ? "" : b.Item
        };
    return View(empList);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `b.Item` is not a `string`?

Comment: Please provide the error and the code of the classes?